# What happens memory wise when copying member function and variables from one object to another

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have two objects and a using function like this:

```
function using(namespace, scope){
    for(x in namespace){
        scope[x] = namespace[x];
    }
}

function fooClass(){
    this.foo = function(){
        console.log("foo");
    }

    this.bar = function(){
        console.log("bar");
    }
}

var myFoo = new fooClass();

function barClass(){
    using(myFoo, this);
}

var myBar = new barClass();
myBar.foo();
```

In this example, it carries over everything from fooClass in to barClass. This is a small example of a vary large scale situation I am looking into doing this. The `namespace` that I am working with in my actual use case is rather large. I know javscript passes by reference for all objects. Some items from the `namespace` are arrays of objects or individual objects that contain arrays of objects or simply just functions. Most primitive variables are private so they should not carry over.

I am curious how much data I am duplicating and how much data I am referencing? Objects stored in the `namespace` should be referenced, but what about functions? Are they copied like a primitive variable or referenced? More so, should I be concerned about memory consumption with this `using()` function?

The main reason I wrote it was because sometimes I'm having to make a call to a deeply nested object and this makes the code more readable, but I do not want to do this if I am sacrificing memory.

Comment: Functions are objects, so properties that refer to functions are really no different from properties that refer to any other sort of object.

Comment: I thought this might have been the case. What confused me was when I took snapshots of the heap in Chrome dev tools, sometimes the original namespace would be larger in bytes, and sometimes the new variable would be larger. So I thought I might look for clarification.

Comment: FWIW only the pointers gets copied. Depending on interpreter it may be more than 4/8 bytes (32/64 bit pointers) but it's still a small amount of memory per object "copied" (actually they're not copied per your example but just linked by pointers)

Comment: One note though, every time you create an instance of `fooClass`, the functions inside `fooClass` get redeclared (re-created from scratch). So two instances of `fooClass` will take twice the memory

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir For sure. In my actual use case the equivalent of the fooClass only gets created once. Though there may be multiple objects using this `using()` function on the fooClass objects' "namespace"

Comment: @slebetman That is actually exactly what I wanted to hear. This means that people developing with my system can use the `using()` function without taking up ridiculous amounts of memory. If you would like to repost that as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Methods are usually attached to the class rather than individual objects, so you don't need to copy anything at all.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure exactly what you are getting at there. My concern is that I have an object that I am using as a namespace. I was creating a way to "use" the namespace in a different function or object similar to using a namespace in C++. Unless I am misunderstanding your comment, I do not think it pertains to my use case.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of individual objects within a class.

Comment: But if this is just for namespaces, why are you worried about the memory use? It's common to make many objects in a class, but do you really use the namespace in a different namespace so many times that the memory use is significant?

Comment: Potentially, yes. The namespace is an API that other executable apps are written with. The executable apps are their own objects outside of the namespace but then a reference to the object is added into the namespace to register it as a running app. The original namespace can potentially get called a lot, and with the way this is starting to build up I just wanted to verify I wasn't duplicating everything with this using function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying `namespace` properties to `space` using `for ... in`, all primitive and object reference values are duplicated so they take up twice as much memory.

JavaScript object values (which include function objects) are held in variables as references to "somewhere" in memory that holds object properties. The copy operation only duplicates the reference, not underlying property names and values or function code, so additional memory consumed by creating a copy is similar to copying a primitive value.

For the use case presented however, you may wish to extend the base `myFoo` object so it is inherited by `barClass` instances. This does mean, of course, that no snapshot of `mFoo` is taken, and `myBar` instances would  inherit any future changes to `myFoo`.

ES5 example:

```js
let myFoo = {foo: "foo"};

function myBar() {
    this.bar = "bar";
}
myBar.prototype = Object.create( myFoo);
myBar.constructor = myBar;

let bar = new myBar();
console.log( bar.foo);
```

ES2015 requires a little more work to create an intermediate function to extend an object **which is not a function**:

```js
let myFoo = {foo: "foo"};
function interFoo() {
};
interFoo.prototype = myFoo;
   
class myBar extends interFoo {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.bar = "bar";
   }
}

let bar = new myBar();
console.log( bar.foo);
```

Note that if you extend `fooClass` directly (the constructor of `myFoo`), creating instances of `barClass` would recreate all properties locally by calling `forClass` as the super class constructor - which is probably not what you want.

Comment: To clarify, "When copying namespace properties to space using for ... in, all primitive and object reference values are duplicated so they take up twice as much memory" you mean that the references would take up twice as much memory but there is still only one instance of the object/function it points to?

Comment: @Xandor - yes that is what I mean. For example with respect to this tour of [V8 object representation](https://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8--object-representation), copying an object value duplicates a pointer to the "JSObject" box. It does not attempt to duplicate the linkages and values within the object - which is called "cloning" an object.

Comment: Excellent. I think for my particular case I won't extend the original namespace object by default and instead continue to use the `using()` function. I feel this leaves it more open for developers using my system to go either route. Regardless, thanks for the detailed information, this was exactly what I wanted to know.